# Material UI CssBaseline conflicting with twin.macro GlobalStyles in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styled-components, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Material UI as my UI library in a Next.js project. I style custom components with the `styled` import from [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro#styled-components).

The [GlobalStyles setup](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/next-styled-components#add-the-global-styles) recommended by `twin.macro` is overriding the [CssBaseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdJef.png) component provided by Material UI. If I remove `GlobalStyles` then `CssBaseline` seems to work fine but it makes the Tailwind classes stop working.

How do I make sure that Material UI `CssBaseline` takes precedence but Tailwind classes still work? Or is using Tailwind with Material UI a bad idea altogether?

**Before removing GlobalStyles:**

```
// _app.tsx
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { TwGlobalStyles } from "../src";
import "../src/styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <TwGlobalStyles /> // <GlobalStyles /> from twin.macro
      <CssBaseline />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

**After removing TwGlobalStyles:**

[image]